# Can Twilio API bulk message on whatsapp?

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, whatsapp

How do I bulk send to ALL customers without the foreach I did. I just want to send to everyone in 1 message.

```
public function sendToMany(Request $request){

    $number = getenv('TWILIO_NUMBER'); //Twilio's number

    $sid    = getenv('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID');//////////////////////
    $token  = getenv('TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'); // API credentials  //
    $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);    //////////////////////

    $otp = $request->message;//message from the form

    $receiver = array("+xxxxxxxxxxxx", "+xxxxxxxxxxxx", "+xxxxxxxxxxxx");

    foreach ($receiver as $receiver_number){
        $message = $twilio->messages 
        ->create("whatsapp:".$receiver_number, // to 
                array( 
                    "from" => "whatsapp:".$number,    
                    "body" => $otp  //message to send
                ) 
                );
    }//end of for loop
}//end of method
```

Comment: How twilio will provide that service while the native WhatsApp API is not providing that service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bulk API for sending messages over WhatsApp using the Twilio API. We recommend you loop through your numbers, as you have done here, or loop through and queue up background jobs that make the API requests independently.

Comment: this is extremely inefficient when you try to send to 3k+ customers

Comment: That’s why I’d recommend background jobs for this many messages. It’s definitely not a good idea to do this in one web process.